# 'Return to question' is not clickable on the Revisions page

Tags: bug, design

I was looking at the [revisions](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/43119/revisions) of this post: [What is Tanam in Music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/what-is-tanam-in-music)

And while on the revisions page, the `Return to question` is not clickable:

[image]

I  cannot highlight it with my mouse either. The same happens in answers as well, [like for instance](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/20504/revisions)

Comment: seems to be related to the header, see [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/the-header-is-preventing-question-links-to-be-clickable)